# Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used headers I have given code of page and route used in it the project is deployed but giving error

Tags: next.js13

the route code is given below

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth"
import { authOptions } from "@/libs/authOptions"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import prisma from '@/libs/prismadb'


export async function GET(req:Request)
{
    try {
        
        const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)

        if(!session)
        {
            throw new Error('Not Authenticated')
        }

        const currentUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where:{
                email:session.user?.email as string
            }
        })

        if(!currentUser)
        {
            throw new Error('Not Authenticated')
        }

        const dumps = await prisma.dumpBox.findMany({
            where:{
                userIds:{
                    has:currentUser.id
                }
            }
        })

        return NextResponse.json(dumps)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return NextResponse.json(error)
    }
}
```

the Page Code is given below

```
"use client"

import DumpCard from "@/app/components/DumpCard"
import Navbar from "@/app/components/Navbar"
import fetcher from "@/libs/fetcher"
import { DumpBox } from "@prisma/client"
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"
import useSWR from "swr"

export const dynamic = "force-static";

const Page = () => {


  const {status} = useSession()
  

  const {data:currentUserDupms=[]} = useSWR('/api/dumps',fetcher)

  if (status === "unauthenticated") {
    return redirect("/");
  }

  if(status==='loading')
  {
    return <p>Loading</p>
  }
    
  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <Navbar />
      <div className=" absolute top-[100px] left-20 overflow-x-hidden  w-full mx-auto">
        <div className="w-full grid grid-cols-3 mx-auto gap-y-5 gap-x-4">
          {currentUserDupms.map((DumpData: DumpBox) => (
            <div key={DumpData.id}>
              <DumpCard DumpData={DumpData} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page
```

I am building a Next.js Project and i have deployed in vercel but it is giving dynamic server error the web site is working in my system properly but it is giving dynamic page rendering error help me to resolve this code while i am running yarn build in my teriminal
it is giving error which is mentioned below

error

```
Generating static pages (0/10)  [    ]n [Error]: Dynamic server usage: Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used `headers`. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/dynamic-server-error
    at u (C:\Users\satya\Desktop\BatCave\knight\.next\server\chunks\678.js:8:9073)
    at d (C:\Users\satya\Desktop\BatCave\knight\.next\server\chunks\382.js:30:96466)
    at s (C:\Users\satya\Desktop\BatCave\knight\.next\server\chunks\382.js:25:20314)
    at l (C:\Users\satya\Desktop\BatCave\knight\.next\server\app\api\dumps\route.js:1:1255)
    at C:\Users\satya\Desktop\BatCave\knight\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:42490
    at C:\Users\satya\Desktop\BatCave\knight\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\trace\tracer.js:133:36
    at NoopContextManager.with (C:\Users\satya\Desktop\BatCave\knight\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@opentelemetry\api\index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (C:\Users\satya\Desktop\BatCave\knight\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@opentelemetry\api\index.js:1:518)
    at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (C:\Users\satya\Desktop\BatCave\knight\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@opentelemetry\api\index.js:1:18093)
    at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (C:\Users\satya\Desktop\BatCave\knight\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@opentelemetry\api\index.js:1:18854) {
  description: "Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used `headers`. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/dynamic-server-error",
  digest: 'DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE'
}
```